# Sass scrollbar style mixin working in textarea but not in random container

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm following [this css-tricks.com example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/custom-scrollbars-mixin/), which shares this mixin:

```scss
@mixin scrollbars($size, $foreground-color, $background-color: mix($foreground-color, white,  50%)) {
  // For Google Chrome
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:  $size;
    height: $size;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: $foreground-color;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: $background-color;
  }

  // For Internet Explorer
  & {
    scrollbar-face-color: $foreground-color;
    scrollbar-track-color: $background-color;
  }
}
```

The article shows how to use the mixin:

```scss
body {
  @include scrollbars(10px, pink, red);
}
.custom-area {
  @include scrollbars(.5em, slategray);
}
```

In my case, I applied it to a `.textarea`:

```scss
.scrollable {
    @include scrollbars(.3em, #bbb, #245662);
}

.textarea {
    border: 5px solid #73B3C9;
    background: #245662;
    padding: 15px;
    @extend .scrollable;
}
```

It works, and I can see that the Sass code successfully replaces the system built-in scrollbar style. However, I'm now trying to apply this `.scrollable` class to a random `<div/>`:

```
this.startGameTextArea.innerHTML = `
    <div class="scrollable" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 5px; overflow-x: scroll; width: 600px">
    ...
`;
```

This div doesn't get the scrollbar customized, why?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I don't know why, but it worked with this:

```scss
.scrollable-inc {
    @include scrollbars(.3em, #bbb, #245662);
}

.textarea {
    @extend .scrollable-inc;
}

.scrollable {
    @extend .scrollable-inc;
}
```

I suppose `.scrollable-inc` works as a template once another class extends it?